# netbeans 8.2, maven, inner jar project, static resource and hot deploy

Tags: maven, netbeans, jar, setup-deployment, magnolia

I'm developing a Magnolia web application with module dependencies, using netbeans 8.2, JDK 1.8, Tomcat 8 and maven.

Project is done as follow:

```
One Parent Project, containing everything
One Web Application project
One Module Project (built as jar), containing java and ftl files.
```

When I press "Apply changes" button on Netbeans, java classes contained in the jar are rightly applied in the JVM and this is really good.

This does not happen when I change something on an FTL (a static resource file), contained in the same jar.

How can I tell netbeans to update the whole jar?

Thanks a lot, Davide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven and your jar is declared as a dependency, you can use the yellow arrows in the Output window to execute the project. By clicking this a new window will emerge and you can check "update snapshots".

[image: re-run dialog clicking on yellow arrows NETBEANS]

Comment: Thanks Emilio! I didn't find the yellow arrows in the run windows... Are you talking about click on the project than (green) run on the toolbar?

Comment: sorry it was on "Output" window, here you have an image

Comment: I did it and it finally underlay and redeploy the whole application, so, it take almost the same time than redeploy... :( Thanks a lot!